# How to use BOOST_BIND_OPERATOR( !=, not_equal ) with a class that does not define the != operator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, bind, c++03

This class `Age` has no `operator!=` defined (and I am not able to add).

```
 struct Age
        {
         Age(int i) {integerAge=i; };
         int integerAge;
         bool operator==(const Age& rhs) const { return this->integerAge==rhs.integerAge; };
         //bool operator!=(const Age& rhs) const { return this->integerAge!=rhs.integerAge; }; not availabe
         bool operator<(const Age& rhs) const {return this->integerAge<rhs.integerAge;};
        };
```

Code in c++11 works fine when I do:

```
std::copy_if(v.begin(),v.end(),std::back_inserter(ageof35),boost::bind(&Person::GetAge,_1)==35); //not available in c++03
```

However, porting back to c++03 requires to express same thing as:

```
std::remove_copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(ageof35),boost::bind(&Person::GetAge,_1)!=35);
```

The only difference is now that the `BOOST_BIND_OPERATOR( !=, not_equal )` is requested.

The full example is here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1907a032c397986

In the STL it is sufficient to define `operator<` and `operator==` and the `operator!=` is just a combination of former two. However, the boost bind requires explicitly the `operator!=`.

**How can force boost bind to use the negation of the defined `operator==` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost bind doesn't require any operators. It uses the ones you tell it to use.

Since you have operator `==` and not `!=`, you can get the result you want by combining `!` and `==`, i.e.:

```
!(boost::bind(&Person::GetAge,_1) == 35)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get right: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48acefd725fee3c0

Comment: @ToBe Operator precedence is important. The parentheses are required here.